# How can I install tar package?

Tags: tar

I have an issue with [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) and tar package version 1.27. So I uninstalled the `tar` package in order to install the  older version. But then I didn't find an older version and when I run `sudo apt-get install tar` to install `tar` I got this error:

```
dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /u
```

Tar already depends on tar to install it. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Download the appropriate package:

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tar/tar_1.28-2.1ubuntu0.1_i386.deb  --- 32 bits

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tar/tar_1.28-2.1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  --- 64 bits

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i 
cd /home/(username)/Downloads
dpkg -i tar_1.28-2.1ubuntu0.1_i386.deb
or
dpkg -i tar_1.28-2.1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

If `dpkg` refuses to work, try this:

- Open the file browser in the terminal
- Open the `.deb` file with the archiver manager.
- Extract the file `data.tar.xz`
- Open the `.xz` file with the archiver manager.
- Extract directories bin etc
- Copy the contents of the directories to the directories /bin /etc
- Close the file browser

And continue running:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall tar
```

Comment: trying to open using archive manager : `an error occured while loading the archive`

Comment: trying `apt-get dist-upgrade` : `dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
`

Comment: trying `dpkg -i tar_1.28-2.1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb` : `dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/`

Comment: it worked by dowloading the source and installing it with `make`